# Best practice for binding ncurses' getstr

Tags: c, lua

I'm creating Lua bindings for ncurses and I want to implement `getstr`, which reads in a string from the user. I want the string to be of basically unlimited size, like in Lua, but I am not sure how to implement this. Do I just read in a char array of really large size or do I do some sort of magic with `getch` until I read in a newline?

I see that [lcurses](https://github.com/rrthomas/lcurses/blob/master/lcurses.c) uses `LUAL_BUFFERSIZE` but is this memory efficient? Is it the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard algorithm is to start with a reasonably-sized buffer, and only resize if needed. For user input at the terminal it can be safely assumed that input cannot be expected exceed around a hundred characters or so. Start with a buffer that size, and only if necessary make it larger.

Make sure you are either using `wgetnstr()` so that you can put limits on the size of the input, but I would personally use `wgetch()`.

Once you have the properly-obtained string, put it into a LUA string and clean up memory.

Comment: I appreciate the answer! Could you provide some sample code or links to some sample code? I am quite new to advanced c and I would rather go at this a bit more intelligently than trial and error.